# Quasar 2 в режиме SSR дает ошибку "Cannot find module 'quasar/dist/ssr-directives/index.js"

Tags: vue3, ssr, quasar-framework

По документации Quasar 2 https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/developing-ssr/configuring-ssr пытаюсь запустить режим Server Side Rendering.

1. Поставил чистый Quasar 2.6.6
2. Добавил режим ssr командой `quasar mode add ssr`
3. Пытаюсь запустить режим dev `quasar dev -m ssr` и получаю ошибку

````
App • Building devland SSR directives...
App • Webpack built the devland SSR directives
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933
  const err = new Error(message);
              ^
Error: Cannot find module 'quasar/dist/ssr-directives/index.js'```
````

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ Razvan на такой же вопрос на одном из сайтов от 19 марта 2022.

> Upgrade the global installation of '@quasar/cli' and run "quasar upgrade -i" in it to auto update everything that's necessary.

Примерно так:

1. `yarn global add @quasar/cli@latest`
2. `quasar upgrade -i`

И все взлетело....